# Django Template error

Tags: html, django

I have my base.html and my footer.html in my static/templates folder; however, the {% extends 'base.html' %} gives me an error:

```
Can't find settings for this Django File
```

Here is my footer.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block footer %}
        <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 column" id="footer">
                <div class="large-3 column" id="footer_content">
                                <div class="social_media">
                                        <img src="/media/img/fb.png">
                                        <img src="/media/img/google+.png">
                                        <img src="/media/img/twitter.png">
                                </div>
                                <hr></br>
                                <h4>{{ name }}: {{ slogan }}</h4>
                                <span>&copy; {{ name }} {{ year }}</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

update traceback, and i fixed the bracket, that was my bad.

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/zach/Documents/project/src/dateyear/views.py" in year
  16.                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  25.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  170.         t = get_template(template_name, dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  144.     template, origin = find_template(template_name, dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  132.             source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in __call__
  44.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in load_template
  50.             template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template_from_string
  156.     return Template(source, origin, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  132.         self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_string
  162.     return parser.parse()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  288.                     self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in invalid_block_tag
  344.         raise self.error(token, "Invalid block tag: '%s'" % command)

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: Invalid block tag: 'endblock'
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: Yeah, I just posted it.

Comment: You may need to post your `base.html` as well, sorry.

Comment: It's likely an issue with an improperly closed tag, or an extra `{% endblock %}` somewhere.  As @vishen said, without the `base.html` file, we can't know for sure.  A tip (and best practice) though, is to use `{% endblock BLOCKNAME %}`  (in this instance, it would be `{% endblock footer %}`.  It helps with lots of things, including readability and troubleshooting issues like these.

Answer (score -1):

In your template, you have an extra (div closing tag) <(/div)> at the end which might be causing the problem!!!